# Access the web project's folder from the WebAPI project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

[image]

My Asp.Net MVC project's folder structure is as shown above.Could you tell me how to access the web project's `event-images` folder from the webapi project ?

I have implemented where I can access the webapi's `event-images` folder as shown below. Now I need to access web project's `event-images`folder.How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

```
  var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
  var pathToEventImage= path + "\\Resources\\images\\event-images\\"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How about:

   ```
   HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
   ```

   Described here: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

   And then navigating to the `Web` project from there.
2. Another way is to go to `Resources` in the API project right click on the folder and choose `Add -> Existing Item..` then browse the Web folder and have it in both projects
3. Another way (if the Web project is also hosted) is to browse it by
   URL. For example http://localhost:1337/Web/Resources/images/event-images/doge.png

**OP's Solution :** I have done the way which **@Pap** mentioned.That is :

> You should have all your images in the "event-images" folder in your
>   API project and then have a method to access them(in the API project,
>   should be part of your API).

Comment: I need to do it in other way around.That is , I need to set the path to `event_images` in the web project's folder from the webApi project.

Comment: It does not take the `web` part.It takes like this :`http://localhost:12534/Resources/images/event-images/3e0c2aaf-265d-486b-8ec5-406729d96a71.jpg` .Then how can I set the path to `web project` within `webapi` ?

Comment: @Sampath. The way you're trying to do it is wrong. You should have all your images in the "event-images" folder in your API project and then have a method to access them(in the API project, should be part of your API). This way, you can call this method from the Web project as well. Within this method, you can access the event images folder the way you do now, or use the `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` as suggested by @gyosifov

Comment: @Sampath I am glad that you resolved your problem. Basically the third bullet point of my answer is the same, but using the Web instead of the Api projects. For some reason I thought that the pictures have to be in the Web project :D